# IF something OR something else THEN - can this condition go on 1 line?

Tags: php, wordpress, conditional-statements

I am tying to add conditional logic for showing a page to logged in users. I have 2 conditions which do not allow them to see page but instead restricted content message. Only 1 has to be true

1) They are not the Author of a form
2) They do not have a custom field called "member"

```
if( $_GET['gform_post_id'] <= 0 || $user != $author ) {
//Then show restricted content message
}
```

The above code is working for the first condition. But I am not sure how to add the 2nd part. I guess it would be an `elseif`

I guess in theory I could duplicate the restricted message by doing something like this

```
if( $_GET['gform_post_id'] <= 0 || $user != $author ) {
//Then show restricted content message
} elseif {
if($memberstatus == 'member'){
//Then show restricted content message
}
```

The reason I do not think this si good solution is my "Restricte Content" is quite large as I write a page with Divs in HTML basically. So it looks a little clumsy in the code to duplicate this twice.

So my question is: Is there a way to write the conditions on the same line?

i.e.

```
IF Condition 1 OR Condition 2 {
//Then show restricted content message
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Can you write it out in plain english instead of pseudo code?

Comment: You can put as many conditions as you want with `||` between them to mean "either of these conditions is true"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What about this?

```
if(($_GET['gform_post_id'] <= 0 || $user != $author) || $memberstatus == 'member' ) {
    //Then show restricted content message
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If I understand you right, you want this :

```
if( ($_GET['gform_post_id'] <= 0 || $user != $author) || $memberstatus == 'member' ) {
   //Then show restricted content message
}
```